# how can call function multiple times with different values in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, timer, call

I have a function that i want call it two or there times at same time with diffrent values for example:

```
var stopClock = false;

function myTimer(clockTime, inClockFunction) {

    stopClock = false;
    ChatClock = {
        totalSeconds: 0,
        start: function () {
            this.interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (!stopClock) {
                    inClockFunction()
                }
                else {
                    ChatClock.pause();
                }
            }, clockTime);
        },
        pause: function () {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            delete this.interval;
        }
    };  
    ChatClock.start();  
}

var time1 = 5000;
var func1 = function() {
   alert(time1)
   stopClock = true;
}
myTimer(5000, func1 )

var time2 = 8000;
var func2 = function() {
    alert(time2)
}
myTimer(8000, func2 )
```

func2 will not show alert because stopClock variable changed to true in func1, how can call multiple times with different values?

Comment: Can you tell us what this code is doing and what are you trying to achieve? It is not clear at all.

Comment: I want it do some works for chat room, every 5 seconds it will get data from database and every 8 seconds will show data to users

Comment: in C# i remember that there could define a class for timer and call two new class that have diffrent values, here i don't know how can do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You variable `stopClock` is global, so both functions access same variable value. Initialize variable only inside function and you should be fine. Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4ur6q33/) for you.

Your javascript has more public/private variables & functions conflicts. Here's another [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b4ur6q33/2/) with all of them(necessary for code to function) fixed.

```
var timeris = function myTimer(clockTime, inClockFunction) {

    var stopClock = false;
    var ChatClock = {
        totalSeconds: 0,
        start: function () {
            this.interval = setInterval(function () {
                if (!stopClock) {
                    stopClock = inClockFunction();
                }
                else {
                    ChatClock.pause();
                }
            }, clockTime);
        },
        pause: function () {
            clearInterval(this.interval);
            delete this.interval;
        }
    };  
    ChatClock.start();  
}

var time1 = 5000;
var func1 = function() {
   alert(time1);
   return true;
}
aa = new timeris(5000, func1 );

var time2 = 8000;
var func2 = function() {
    alert(time2);
    return false;
}
bb = new timeris(8000, func2 );
```

Comment: you did solve stopClock problem but i found another problem that stopClock can't stop func1 and func1 will show every 5 second when i want it show func1 alert just one time, please help to solve that too

Comment: @MojtabaSh i have edited my answer with fixes. Main problem is wrong declarations of public & private variables